# Vertically Align qedsymbol in final proof equation

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsthm

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                                              
\usepackage{amsmath}                                                                                                                                                                             
\usepackage{amsthm}                                                                                                     
\newcommand{\f}{\frac{a}{a}}                                                                                            
\begin{document}                                                                                                        
\begin{proof}                                                                                                           
\begin{align*}                                                                                                          
 1 &= \frac{\frac{\f}{\f}}{\frac{\f}{\f}} \qedhere                                                                      
\end{align*}                                                                                                            
\end{proof}                                                                                                             
\end{document}
```

We have a proof, that is ended by some formula with `\qedhere`.
But the `\qedsymbol` appears on the center of the line rather than at the bottom.
Here is what this looks like:

[image: Compiled MWE]

**Question**: 
How to vertically align the `\qedsymbol` to the bottom of the line 
(i.e. align the lower border of the lowest `a` with the lower border of the `\qedsymbol`)?

Comment: The “bottom of the line” is exactly where the symbol is placed.

Comment: Well, then the "bottom of the line" seems to be ambiguous. How would you call the kind of alignment I'm interested in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A work-around by trial and error: add a new empty line of alignment and raise it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\newcommand{\f}{\frac{a}{a}}
\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
\begin{align*}
 1 &= \frac{\frac{\f}{\f}}{\frac{\f}{\f}}\\[-0.82\baselineskip] & \qedhere%\r
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better than I initially thought. The `-.82` does not depend on the actual formula content, but rather merely on the line spacing. Correct?

Comment: I've just tested, and you seem to be right: adding another fraction doesn't seem to modify the alignment. I would have bet that it would change the alignment…

Comment: It's addmittedly hacky; but it can easily be hidden inside some helper and imposes no requirements on the formula. I like it.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't do it. Prefer ending proofs with a sentence, rather than a formula. Or leave the tombstone where it is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newcommand{\f}{\frac{a}{a}}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\begin{equation*}
\raisebox{\depth}{$\displaystyle 1 = \frac{\frac{\f}{\f}}{\frac{\f}{\f}}$} \qedhere
\end{equation*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for both your expert recommendations and this working answer. Could you elaborate what `\displaystyle` is for? Could you still align in a `\raisebox` (ie. `&=`)?

I'm surprised by this solution. I was rather expecting a box for `\qedhere` of some sort...

Comment: @m8mble No, you can't (easily) do it for the last line of `align`. I use `\displaystyle` to get the same math style as it's used in `equation`.